# Как узнать режим работы опимизатора Oracle(optimizer_mode) для конкретной сесиии?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Я могу посмотреть режим работы оптимизатора для БД таким запросом:

```
select valuer
from   v$parameter t
where  t.name = 'optimizer_mode'
```

Как теперь это же значение можно посмотреть для конкретной сессии?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Представление [V$SES_OPTIMIZER_ENV](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-F472665A-1C43-473F-8DE3-98EA2B3C1026.htm#REFRN30308), то, что вам нужно.

> `V$SES_OPTIMIZER_ENV` displays the contents of the optimizer
>   environment used by each session. When a new session is first created,
>   it automatically inherits its optimizer environment from the optimizer
>   environment defined at the instance level by `V$SYS_OPTIMIZER_ENV`.
>   The value of certain parameters can be dynamically modified by issuing
>   an `ALTER SESSION` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Можно связать сессию с конкретным запросом, и уже для запроса смотреть, в каком режиме строился план:

```
select s.sid
      ,t.OPTIMIZER_MODE
from   v$session s
left   join v$sql t
on     s.sql_id = t.SQL_ID;
```

Недостатки:

- В сессии должен выполняться запрос.
- Режимом построения плана можно управлять с помощью хинтов. Так для сессии может быть выставлен один режим, но запрос построится в другом.

Comment: можно еще в [V$SES_OPTIMIZER_ENV](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-F472665A-1C43-473F-8DE3-98EA2B3C1026.htm#REFRN30308) посмотреть